# JavaFX TableView: Show sorted items + Background Task

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm working with Javafx and I'm struggling to get a sorted table in place when using background Tasks to update. In the code [here](https://gist.github.com/galderz/02744e4cb034c5859f30ebf822746029), which can be run standalone, I update a table in background.

What I'd like to do is that this table gets updated, and stays sorted in chronological order, so older train times appear at the top, and later ones at the bottom. The example produces times that are the opposite order on purpose, to see if sorting works.

I run some tests before I added concurrent update to the table, and the way I would do it is by calling:

```
private final ObservableList<StationBoardLine> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
      new StationBoardLine("RE", "17:14", "Basel Bad Bf", "Basel SBB", "+3", "RE 5343"));
SortedList<StationBoardLine> sorted = new SortedList<>(data, new DelayComparator());
table.setItems(sorted);
```

However, now I'm not setting the items, but using the background task together with `ReadOnlyObjectProperty` and `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` to append to it.

So, my question is, how can I make sure that as items are added, the list remains ordered? I've tried to see if I could reorder the list inside the call to `Platform.runLater` but didn't seem to work.

The link between the task updating the table and the table is set is here:

```
table.itemsProperty().bind(task.partialResultsProperty());
```

Thanks for help,

Galder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is by updating an ObservableList by the background task and use it as a "source" to create a SortedList. This SortedList would then act as the source of "items" to the TableView.

A general structure would be :

```
public class MyClass {

    private TableView<T> tableView = new TableView;
    private ObservableList<T> sourceList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public MyClass() {
       ...
       SortedList<T> sortedList = new SortedList<>(sourceList, new MyComparator());
       tableView.setItems(sortedList);

       ...

       new Task<Void> {
           protected Void call() {
             ... // Some background data fetch
             Platform.runLater(() -> sourceList.add(data));
             return null;
           }
       };
   }
}
```

For your scenario, I would go with something that you already have. Therefore, instead of creating a new ObservableList to be used as a source for your SortedList, I would use the list returned by `Task#getPartialResults()`.

The DelayComparator uses the value of the delay to compare and show the data in the TableView.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class App extends Application {

    private TableView<StationBoardLine> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn typeCol = getTableCol("Type", 10, "type");
        TableColumn departureCol = getTableCol("Departure", 30, "departure");
        TableColumn stationCol = getTableCol("Station", 200, "station");
        TableColumn destinationCol = getTableCol("Destination", 200, "destination");
        TableColumn delayCol = getTableCol("Delay", 20, "delay");
        TableColumn trainName = getTableCol("Train Name", 50, "trainName");

        table.getColumns().addAll(
                typeCol, departureCol, stationCol, destinationCol, delayCol, trainName);

        root.setCenter(table);

        PartialResultsTask task = new PartialResultsTask();
        SortedList<StationBoardLine> sorted = new SortedList<>(task.getPartialResults(), new DelayComparator());
        table.setItems(sorted);
        exec.submit(task);

        stage.setTitle("Swiss Transport Delays Board");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private TableColumn getTableCol(String colName, int minWidth, String fieldName) {
        TableColumn<StationBoardLine, String> typeCol = new TableColumn<>(colName);
        typeCol.setMinWidth(minWidth);
        typeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(fieldName));
        return typeCol;
    }

    static final class DelayComparator implements Comparator<StationBoardLine> {

        @Override
        public int compare(StationBoardLine o1, StationBoardLine o2) {
            return o1.getDelay().compareTo(o2.getDelay());
        }

    }

    public class PartialResultsTask extends Task<Void> {

        private ObservableList<StationBoardLine>partialResults = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        public final ObservableList<StationBoardLine> getPartialResults() {
            return partialResults;
        }

        @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Creating station board entries...");
            for (int i=5; i >= 1; i--) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if (isCancelled()) break;
                StationBoardLine l = new StationBoardLine(
                        "ICE", "16:" + i, "Basel Bad Bf", "Chur", String.valueOf(i), "ICE 75");
                Platform.runLater(() -> partialResults.add(l));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static final class StationBoardLine {
        private final SimpleStringProperty type;
        private final SimpleStringProperty departure;
        private final SimpleStringProperty station;
        private final SimpleStringProperty destination;
        private final SimpleStringProperty delay;
        private final SimpleStringProperty trainName;

        StationBoardLine(String type,
                         String departure,
                         String station,
                         String destination,
                         String delay,
                         String trainName) {
            this.type = new SimpleStringProperty(type);
            this.departure = new SimpleStringProperty(departure);
            this.station = new SimpleStringProperty(station);
            this.destination = new SimpleStringProperty(destination);
            this.delay = new SimpleStringProperty(delay);
            this.trainName = new SimpleStringProperty(trainName);
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty typeProperty() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type.set(type);
        }

        public String getDeparture() {
            return departure.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty departureProperty() {
            return departure;
        }

        public void setDeparture(String departure) {
            this.departure.set(departure);
        }

        public String getStation() {
            return station.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty stationProperty() {
            return station;
        }

        public void setStation(String station) {
            this.station.set(station);
        }

        public String getDestination() {
            return destination.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty destinationProperty() {
            return destination;
        }

        public void setDestination(String destination) {
            this.destination.set(destination);
        }

        public String getDelay() {
            return delay.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty delayProperty() {
            return delay;
        }

        public void setDelay(String delay) {
            this.delay.set(delay);
        }

        public String getTrainName() {
            return trainName.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty trainNameProperty() {
            return trainName;
        }

        public void setTrainName(String trainName) {
            this.trainName.set(trainName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Your suggestion seems to work :D